# Черный экран на Windows сервере после замены через реестр cmd на powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Всем привет!
У меня есть виртуальная машина, на ней установлен сервер Exchange. Мне понадобилось изменить, чтобы по умолчанию команды исполнялись в powershell, а не в cmd. Нашел такую команду и применил:

`Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon'-Name Shell -Value 'PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "Set-Location ~"'`

Перезагрузил сервер, подключился по RDP и увидел только черный экран. Открывается только окно "Диспетчер серверов".

Есть возможность откатить все назад? Я так понимаю в принципе вносить изменения в реестр было плохой идеей и так лучше не делать?